# Which heroes can make this jump in Numbani?

Tags: overwatch

I was wondering if it is possible to flank around this building on Numbani behind Point A. I marked the path in green in the following picture.

[image: Green Path Image]

I was thinking that maybe Pharah could fly around it, but can anyone actually make it around the building? If so, it seems like it would be a helpful flank as people would not expect you to come around that side. For reference, here's a screenshot from the area behind Point A.

[image: View from Point A]

A successful jump would land you near the golden statue on the other side of the building.

Comment: Off-the-cuff and entirely untested: Lucio can probably make it. He can get pretty much anywhere if there's a wall to ride.

Comment: @txteclipse hmm, yea likely. there is the building that he can most likely ride around.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I got a bit of time and tested this. The heroes you can do this with are

- Pharah with Jump Jet and Hover, she is also the only one who can navigate this both directions.
- Genji with a combination of double jump into wall climb into jump into swift strike (I found him the hardest to do this with).
- Tracer with a jump off into triple blink.
- D.Va can fly around the building with her jets.
- Lucio can wall ride around the building
- Mercy, as she can fly after her teammate if she has a teammate who can clear the gap.

I was not able to do this with Winston, Widowmaker, or Junkrat.

Comment: I figured out that you can build an ice wall with Mei on the gold part of the building above the door: it might help Winston since he could jump jet up to that and then jump jet again. On that note, the ice wall will happily hang halfway off the ledge over the grass area, making the initial jump for any character much easier.

Comment: @txteclipse i'll have to try that. i was playing solo, so couldnt test any pairs

Comment: Did you try this with D.Va's boosters, by chance?

Comment: @Pants oh yes. I forgot to add her to the list.

Comment: Just wondering did you try double concussion mine with junkrat? Place a mine and wait for cd. Jump with the mine and use another mine mid air.

Comment: @ModDL I did try and failed about 15 times.

Comment: So not a practical method

Answer (score 0):

Winston *can* make this route if you trigger his ultimate at half way: